# How to set freedrawing mode in fabric js to Circle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

How to make the freeDrawing mode to circle , by default it is coming as rectangle.
What I mean is when I select a region it is getting selected as Rectangle as default for free drawing mode.

How to make it for Circle?

`canvas.freeDrawingBrush = "Circle"` doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

To set DrawingBrush **circle** try this:

```
canvas.freeDrawingBrush = new fabric.CircleBrush(canvas);
```

But it will not allow you to **draw circle** in canvas. It will just set the **DrawingBrush** circular.

Comment: No ,it doesn't still I am getting the same rectangle as selector. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is still the same . Can you please add a jsfiddle for the answer